# Do pad functions of QGIS Field Calculator have bug?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I have this expression in the field calculator:

`regexp_replace('1', '^(\\d+)', rpad('\\1', 3, '0') )` gives `01` rather than `001` as expected.

the *pad functions work fine when called outside regexp_replace

Weird!   This has to be a bug? or am I missing something?

If it is a bug I'll log something in the issue tracker.

BTW I was delighted when I found I could use complex expressions including functions in the third parameter of `regexp_replace`!   kudos to the QGIS developers!

Comment: What does `rpad('22',3,'0')` give you?

Comment: '022' as expected.  The problem appears when the *pad function is called in regexp_replace.  I'll edit the main question to insert an image from the calculator that uses static strings.

Comment: I ended up radically simplifying the question to use a static example.

Comment: Shouldn't it be lpad rather than rpad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a bug in any of the functions, more an implementation detail that isn't evident at first look.

The expression engine evaluates from inside out, so rpad is run first with no concept of the outer function or the regex.

This is run first:

```
rpad('\\1', 3, '0')
```

which it looks at and goes "Ok cool I can pad that for you".  The result:

```
\10
```

the `\\` will escape the `\` so you end up with it in your final output. Three characters just like you asked for, well as far as the expression is concerned.

By the time your `regexp_replace` runs it looks like this:

```
regexp_replace('3', '^(\\d+)', '\10' )
```

and at that point `regexp_replace` is doing what it is told. Replacing the first group with replace string. So you end up with `30`.

Comment: I was very surprised when this appeared to work at all.  I am guessing I need to do this in a script of some sort.

Comment: or just increase the pad number by 1 :)

Comment: I did that before I posted the question ;)